# If statement should check if user email exists, and then make the role admin.. but it is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am actually wondering the best way to do this. I am going to have an array of user emails that will automatically be assigned to the role of admin when they register. I need the method to check if the email is on the list, assign it to admin, and if it is not, assign it to customer. Here is how I am trying to create it, but it isn't working...

```
  def set_role
    if self[:email] = "douglaswalter2@gmail.com" 
        self[:role] = "admin" 
    else
      self[:role] = "customer"
    end
  end
```

I will then also call,

```
before_create :set_role
```

If the list of users is in an array... Should I keep this list in seceret.yml?

Comment: You should use `==` in your condition logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby the operator '=' is an assignment variable. You need to use the comparison operator '=='. This will check for the condition you are looking for.

```
 def set_role
    if self[:email] == "douglaswalter2@gmail.com" 
        self[:role] = "admin" 
    else
      self[:role] = "customer"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
  def set_role
    if self[:email] == "douglaswalter2@gmail.com" 
        self[:role] = "admin" 
    else
      self[:role] = "customer"
    end
  end
```

Comment: So I guess that does fix that issue... However, an insight on storing it in a secret array?